# Delphi - check if a Unicode character occurs in a set of characters?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

This code works good with Delphi-7 (until Delphi had Unicode support):

```
Value := edit1.Text[1];
    
if Value in ['м', 'ж'] then ...
```

**'м', 'ж'** - cyrillic symbols

But this construction doesn't work with Unicode charachter.
I try a lot of things, but they are doesn't work.
I also tried changing the value types to "Char" and "AnsiChar".

****Doesn't** work:**

```
const
  MySet : set of WideChar = [WideChar('м'), WideChar('ж')];
begin
  Value := edit1.Text[1];
  if Value in MySet then ...
```

****Doesn't** work:**

```
if AnsiChar(Value) in ['м', 'ж'] then ...
```

****Doesn't** work:**

```
if CharInSet(Value, ['м', 'ж']) then ...
```

**But this works good:**

```
  if (Value = 'м') or (Value = 'ж') then ...
```

Whether there is an opportunity to check up UNICODE character by use of a **SET** in the modern versions of Delphi?
Or should we check each character individually?

*My Delphi version is 10.4 update 2 Community Edition*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Delphi set type can only handle a maximum of 256 values, so it cannot be used for handling Unicode characters. For handling Unicode, the `System.Character` unit provides various methods and helpers.

For this particular case, there is an `IsInArray()` character helper you can use. Instead of declaring a set of characters, you will need to declare an array of characters:

```
var
  ch: Char;
  a: array of Char;
  s: string;
begin
  a := ['м', 'ж'];
  s := 'abcж';
  for ch in s do
    if ch.IsInArray(a) then ...
end;
```

Note: Delphi XE7 introduced additional language support for initializing and working with dynamic arrays, and square brackets can also be used for simpler array initialization. In the context of above example, `['м', 'ж']` is not a set, but an array of wide characters.

Comment: It might be worth to point out that `['м', 'ж']` is NOT a Delphi set (despite its appearance!), but an array using the XE7+ syntax. `a` is a dynamic array of characters. `IsInArray` has time complexity O(n), while the old `x in S` has time complexity O(1).

Comment: @Andreas Does the in operator for set membership in Delphi really have time complexity O(1)? I'm not at all sure that is true.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Well, since the `in` operator works on Delphi sets which never have more than 256 elements, it's almost meaningless to even discuss its time complexity, isn't it?  But you are right: I don't know precisely how the time used by the operation depends on the size of the set type as it varies from 1 byte to 32 bytes (the maximum size); it may well be close to log(n) or something, as far as I know.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Well, it was you that brought up time complexity! ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know! The O(1) remark about `in` wasn't particularly clever.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Considering the "in" operator on a set should only check if the Nth bit of the set is on (+ probably some range checking), I think the O(1) assumption is quite valid.

Comment: @KenBourassa: That was my intuition as well. But I am sure we can all agree that the entire concept of asymptotic behaviour of `in` is meaningless in practice given the bounds of `n`.

Comment: @Andreas Thinking about this, it is O(1) because of the data type. A predetermined bit is reserved for each element of the base type. Same would be true if you made a set of WideChar in the same way, were the language to support it. In fact you can make such a thing with operator overloads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, that was my initial reasoning as well. Actually, a set of WideChar would almost be realistic, since such a variable would "only" have a size of 8 kB. A `set of Integer` variable would require 512 MB. It seems unlikely I'll ever see a `set of Int64` variable during my lifetime, though.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Although set of WideChar wouldn't be much use with surrogates, combining characters etc.

Answer (score 1):

> check if a Unicode character occurs in a set of characters?

Do you mean a Delphi [set](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets)?

In general, it is impossible to have a `set of X` where the base type `X` has more than 256 possible distinct values. So `set of Byte` is fine, but `set of Word` isn't possible. Since there are 256 * 256 distinct wide character values, it is therefore impossible to have a set of wide characters. (If this were indeed possible, a variable of such a set type would be 8 kB in size. That would be an unusually large variable.)

Since there is no such thing as "Delphi set of Unicode characters", the question "How to see if a character belongs to a Delphi set of Unicode characters" doesn't make sense.

Or do you simply mean a mathematical set?

If so, of course this is possible, but you cannot use a Delphi set to represent the mathematical set of characters. Instead, you need to use some other data type. One possibility is a simple array, if you don't mind its O(n) characteristics.

Comment: Yes, I mean the Unicode character set
But why then does the construction with Latin characters work, but not with Cyrillic? (Perhaps the reason for this is political sanctions?)

edit1.Text[1] in ['a', 'b'] - work good.
edit1.Text[1] in ['м', 'ж'] - doesn't work.

Comment: The simplest way to represent chars in computers is to let each byte represent a character (glyph). Then 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 254, 255 each represent a character. For instance, A is represented by 65 and T by 84. The question mark, ?, is 63. But all the languages of the world has more than 256 letters combined. (Many, many more.) So a character set and encoding able to represent all these characters need to use more than a single byte per character. A Delphi `Char` uses 2 bytes, so you have 16 bits and 2^16 = 65536 different characters. This is enough to represent many languages properly.

Comment: (cont.) For instance, `ж` has codepoint U+0436, so it is simply the integer $436. ஷ is U+0BB7. ڇ is U+0687. ᚶ is U+16B6. फ़ is U+095E. ಮ is U+0CAE. య is U+0C2F. ඤ is U+0DA4. ኊ is U+128A. Ꮿ is U+13EF. ᦿ is U+19BF. ∰ is U+2230. ꖠ is U+A5A0 and so on. If you need more than 256 chars, you need more than a byte, and you cannot use a Delphi set.

Comment: (cont.) Then you may ask, "Why is English so special so its letters are assigned to the first 127 integers?" Well, likely because English was very widely used in the early era of computers in the 1900s. As a native Swedish speaker, I am unable to represent my favourite letters Å, Ä, and Ö in ASCII (although there are common 8-bit encodings containing these, like Windows-1252).